# How to convert a tree directory into a single level directory

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

This question might be confused , it's better to show some example.
I have a folder that contain many sub-directory which might be multiple level.The structure below show the folder , all folder do contain their own file.

```
mainFolder
|--a
|--|--ab
|--|--ac
|--|--ad
|--b
|--b
|--|-cd
|--d
```

The above is the tree structure of mainFolder. I am trying to write a batch file that able to convert the whole tree into a single level structure.

```
--a
--ab
--ad
--b
--c
--cd
--d
```

Above is the expected output. All file should be in their own folder.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set "targetPath=%~dp0mainFolder"

for /r "%targetPath%" %%i in (.) do (

     echo %%i

)

pause
```

This is my current code , which able to loop through and display the absolute path of the directory

Comment: Show us your work so far and tell where you're stuck.

Comment: @gronostaj Updated my question. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Your best bet would be to use the `/D` flag and have a recusive BAT file that `CALL`s itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are inconsistencies: in source `--c` is missing in dest there is no `--ac`

Source tree:

```
> tree
└───mainFolder
    ├───a
    │   ├───ab
    │   ├───ac
    │   └───ad
    ├───b
    ├───c
    │   └───cd
    └───d
```

Provided mainfolder is in the root of the drive this single cmdline:

```
@for /r "\mainfolder" %A in (.) do @for /f "tokens=5 delims=\" %B in ("%A") do @move "%A" "\mainFolder"
```

Will produce this destination tree:

```
> tree
└───mainFolder
    ├───a
    ├───ab
    ├───ac
    ├───ad
    ├───b
    ├───c
    ├───cd
    └───d
```

If not adjust the tokens value from 5 to match the dirlevel.
In a batch file double all the percent signs `%%`